# How to use dictionary to create directory of different objects

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning to use dictionaries and am trying to use them to do this specific thing:

I want a user prompt to ask user to select which one of four items is a fruit and then they would see a list of something like 'bird, chair, apple, grass' and they input whichever number the apple is. I want the apple to be in a dictionary with many other fruit where the key of them all is 'fruit'. I also want other dictionaries for different types of furniture where chair would be a part of and something similar for bird. Is this something I could use dictionaries for or am I going the wrong direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indeed use dictionaries for this, I made a quick file for you so you can understand how everything reacts. Take note: I made this for readability, the more you learn about python, the more efficient you will code!

This first defines the function, for easy calling to start over. Then the dictionaires are created, it's not necessary to put them inside the function, but then again; readability.

Some options are printed `\n` inserts an `enter`. that way you don't have 4 print statements underneath each other. 
Then a question is asked `int(input("text"))` makes sure that the answer given is a integer, and not a base 10.

Then there is a simple `if question == 1:` which tells the program what to do when the `question = int(input())` is 1.

Hope you find this helpful and this is what you meant. If not, feel free to comment and I will try to help you as good as I possibly can!

```
def quiz():
    Birds = {'Eagle', 'Parrot', 'Woodpecker', 'Sparrow', 'Pigeon'}
    Furniture = {'Chair', 'Bench', 'Sofa', 'Closet', 'Table'}
    Fruit = {'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Pear', 'Grape', 'Strawberry'}
    Plants = {'Sunflower', 'Cactus', 'Moss', 'Brambles', 'Wheat'}
    print("1. Bird \n2. Chair \n3. Apple \n4. Grass")
    question = int(input("which one is a fruit?: "))
    if question == 1:
        print("Thats wrong! But other kinds of birds are:", ','.join(Birds))
    if question == 2:
        print("Thats wrong! But other kinds of furniture are:", ','.join(Furniture))
    if question == 3:
        print("That's Correct! Other kinds of fruit are:", ','.join(Fruit))
    if question == 4:
        print("Thats wrong! But other kinds of plants are:", ','.join(Plants))

    input("Press Enter to start over")
    quiz()
quiz()
```

Something about dictionaries from https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139052/dictionary-vs-list:

> You would use a Dictionary if your indexes have a special meaning
>   besides just positional placement.
>
> The immediate example that comes to mind is storing an id column and
>   an int column in a database. For example, if you have a [person-id]
>   column and a [personal-pin] column, then you might bring those into a
>   Dictionary. This way pinDict[person-id] gives you a PIN, but
>   the index is meaningful and not just a position in a List.
>
> But really, any time you have two related lists of integers, this
>   could be an appropriate data structure.